# Send a mail when branching or merging is performed in TFS, can anyone help me in starting the coding on this?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

We have multiple teams working on one project.Si say if one team completes its development and he/he merges the branch to the Main branch, I want the mailers to be send to different teams so before they doing an upmerge to Main branch they should first downmerge the Main branch to their specific branches.

Answer (score 1):

Create a checkin alert with `Server Item` `Under` `$/project/Main`, and send to whoever needs to know.